# How to change favicon in quasar framework?

Tags: quasar-framework

How to change favicon in quasar framework? I already tried changing the `href` in `index.template.html` but failed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `href` in three link tags and it works.

Try this.

```
<link rel="icon" href="statics/ninja-simple-512.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="statics/icons/ninja-simple-512.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="statics/icons/ninja-simple-512.png">
```

Comment: You may also need to refresh the browser/ clear cache if you have been using a different favicon previously on that localhost:port combination. I had was getting the vue favicon on a new quasar app which had the correct href pointing to the quasar favicon

Answer (score 2):

For icons purposes, QUASAR have great plugin called
Quasar Framework Icon Genie.
This is a CLI tool to generate all the icons and splash screens for your Quasar Apps.
With this plugin, you just need to put app-icon.png and app-splashscreen.png into your quasar root directory, and after quasar dev or quasar build commands plugin will generate for you perfect favicons, also if you are developing iOS or android application this plugin will generate application icon and splash screen.

```
quasarframework/icongenie
```

[Quasar Framework Icon Genie](https://github.com/quasarframework/icongenie)

Comment: Although doc does mention only apps in icongenie, it can also be used for favicon just like this ``icongenie g -i src/assets/icons/favicon-128x128.png``