# Change favicon in Quasar

Tags: favicon, quasar-framework

I'm trying to change the favicon in Quasar. I tried following what they suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55645903/how-to-change-favicon-in-quasar-framework#), but no result. I tried cleaning the cache, with Icon Genie... nothing worked.
This is my folder structure:

```
.
├── project_name
    ├── src
        ├── index.template.html
        ├── statics
            ├──icons
               ├── favicon.ico
               ├── favicon-16x16.png
               ├── favicon-32x32.png
```

Inside the `index.template.html` I have:

```
<head>
...
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="statics/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="statics/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="statics/icons/favicon.ico">
</head>
```

The icons were generated using `icongenie generate`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code once.

```
├── project_name
    ├── public
        ├──icons
               ├── favicon.ico
               ├── favicon-16x16.png
               ├── favicon-32x32.png
    ├── src
        ├── index.template.html
```

in index.template.html.

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="icons/favicon.ico">
  </head>
```